# Django UpdateView with ImageField attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am having trouble in making UpdateView Class.I was able to do createView and UpdateView without adding any form before adding up the imageField. But now I have imageField, which is creating problem. Fortunately,  I am able to do createView and its working fine.

Following is my code for CreateView

```
class CreatePostView(FormView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'edit_post.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-list')
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(commit=True)
        # messages.success(self.request, 'File uploaded!')
        return super(CreatePostView, self).form_valid(form)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreatePostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('post-new')
        return context
```

However, I tried to do UpdateView(ViewForm). Following is my code :

```
class UpdatePostView(SingleObjectMixin,FormView):
model = Post
form_class = PostForm
tempate_name = 'edit_post.html'

# fields = ['title', 'description','content','published','upvote','downvote','image','thumbImage']

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('post-list')
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save(commit=True)
    # messages.success(self.request, 'File uploaded!')
    return super(UpdatePostView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(UpdatePostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['action'] = reverse('post-edit',
                                kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})
    return context
```

When I try to run the updateView, its giving me following error:

> AttributeError at /posts/edit/23/
>
> 'UpdatePostView' object has no attribute 'get_object'
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     http://localhost:8000/posts/edit/23/ Django Version:    1.8.2 Exception
>   Type:     AttributeError Exception Value:
>
> 'UpdatePostView' object has no attribute 'get_object'
>
> Exception Location:   /home/PostFunctions/mysite/post/views.py in
>   get_context_data, line 72 Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python Python
>   Version:  2.7.6

Following is my url.py :

```
#ex : /posts/edit/3/

url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', post.views.UpdatePostView.as_view(),
    name='post-edit',),
```

Comment: Where was `get_object()` defined?

Comment: could you please help me in figuring out that.?

Comment: Well, that stacktrace is telling you that the error is being thrown because you called a method ('get_object') that hasn't been defined anywhere. That is, unless you didn't post all of your code?

Comment: I have updated the question and added some function, but giving me error global name pk is not defined. I am passing it it through url though.

Comment: @user3487775 delete `queryset` property, `get_queryset()` and `get_object()` methods from your class and look at the answer below.

Comment: any other possibility thats raising error?

Comment: @ozgur Thanks for your time. I am getting following errr: 
'UpdatePostView' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: reverse('post-edit',
                                kwargs={'pk'})

Comment: @gamer still same error

Comment: reverse('post-edit', self.kwargs={'pk'})

Comment: @gamer giving syntax error 
keyword can't be an expression

Comment: sorry its self.kwargs['pk']

Comment: @gamer I tried that one too. giving eror: 
'UpdatePostView' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: Did you already have a look on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31558094/2932052)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a form to update Model with ImageField.
I do extend a ModelForm for my model (which is PostForm for you I guess).

But my CustomUpdateView extend UpdateView, from django generic view.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class CustomUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'some_template.html'
    form_class = CustomModelForm
    success_url = '/some/url'

    def get_object(self): #and you have to override a get_object method
        return get_object_or_404(YourModel, id=self.request.GET.get('pk'))
```

You just have to define a get_object method and update view will update the object with value in form, but it needs to get the object you want to update.

`get_object_or_404()` works like a `get()` function on a Model, so replace id by the name of your field_id.

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried following your example

Its giving error: 

Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/posts/edit/22/
Raised by:  post.views.UpdatePostView

No Post matches the given query.

Comment: However, when I hardcode value, its working. Its just that it cant get the value from url (pk).

get_object_or_404(Post, pk='22') : its working fine
so its need to figure out how to get value from URL

Comment: Did you called CustomUpdateView.as_view() un your URL ?

Comment: it worked,  Thanks
I use def get_object(self): #and you have to override a get_object method
        return get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])